# Allocating space for List inside structure

Tags: c++, stl

I have a structure as follows:

```
struct Vertex{
      list<int> q;
};
```

I created an array of size 10 as follows:

```
Vertex *ver = (Vertex*) malloc(10 * sizeof(Vertex));
```

Now I wish to insert in the list. I am having a hard time figuring out why is it giving a segmentation fault:

```
ver[1].q.push_back(10);
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong here?

Comment: Why not `std::vector<Vertex> ver(10);`?  And it is giving you seg fault because `malloc` doesn't create objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc`just allocates memory, it doesn't construct any objects in that memory.

You could instead try

```
Vertex* ver = new Vertex[10];
```

which *does* initialize the `Vertex` structs and its `list` members.

An even easier way to create 10 `Vertex` objects is

```
std::vector<Vertex>  ver(10);
```

This also saves you from the trouble of having to `delete[]` the objects later.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for your list `q` was never called. Either you use the `new` operator (`Vertex* ver = new Vertex[10];`) or you use `std::vector<Vertex>` instead of `Vertex*`

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::list<int> > q(10);
```

if you need an array of vertices with 3 scalars of type int you should use this:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::vector< std::array<int,3> > q(10);
```